# Align center with media queries (EMAIL CODE)

Tags: email, html-email

This is email code, hence using tables instead of using lists.

If I change the width of the promo_1-3 to be a fixed number (say 300px) I can get them to align left and right (like the original code at the desktop size) but I can't get them to ignore the originally specified left or right alignment and be centered

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 660px) {
        table.container { width: 100% !important; }
        td.logo img { width:100% !important; }
        td.headerimg img{ width: 100% !important; padding: 5px 30px 40px 30px;}
        td.promos table.promo_1 { width: 100% !important; }
        td.promos table.promo_1 td { padding: 20px 20px 40px 30px; }
        td.promos table.promo_2 { width: 100% !important; }
        td.promos table.promo_2 td { padding: 20px 0px 40px 30px; }
        td.promos table.promo_3 { width: 100% !important; border-top: 1px solid #CAC5C5; }
        td.promos table.promo_3 td { padding: 20px 0px 40px 30px; }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!-- Start story 1 -->     
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" bgcolor="#fff" class="promos" style="padding: 10px 10px 20px 20px; background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <table class="promo_3" width="300" align="left">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                             <a target="_blank" href="http://trailrunnermag.com/training/training-plans/1860-what-your-weekly-training-plan-should-look-like"> 
                             <img class="promo" alt="Promo image 1" src=    "http://media.campaigner.com/media/47/474810/063016ID3.jpg"></a>
                                <h3 style="font-size:16px;">Promo heading here</h3>

                                <br><br>
                                    <a href="#" style="background-color: #7711AA; border-radius: 5px; color: #fff; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #3a5606;">Learn more</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly here is the fix:

in your HTML change the line:

```
<table class="promo_3" width="300" align="left">
```

to

```
<table width="300" class="promo_3" align="left">
```

so it applys the class specified atributes after you set the width.
This makes you table then be 100% wide on a smaller screen.
Then change your css line like this:

```
td.promos table.promo_3 { width: 100% !important; border-top: 1px solid #CAC5C5; }
```

to

```
td.promos table.promo_3 { width: 100% !important; text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #CAC5C5; }
```

to align the Content in your table to the center.

Also, if you are using this for an Email, I'd recomend you to not use the H3 because it always gives trouble, since every client interprets it a littble bit different. Instead use a span and apply styles to it.